# Sensitivity analysis of an equation in R language

Tags: r, statistics, montecarlo

I have the equation,

```
Y = A*B*C/(D*E)
```

Where A, B, C, D and E are the certain parameters of 1000 samples (say groundwater samples).

```
A => lognormal distribution = {min = 10, max=50, mean=30}
B => Triangular distribution = {min=5, max = 25, mode = 22}
C => Beta distribution = {min=0.02,max=2.26,alpha=0.657,beta=0.86}
D => Weibull distribution = {location=0, scale=0.06, shape=0.946}
E => gamma distribution = {location=0.03,scale=0.18,shape=1.164}
```

I want to perform sensitivity analysis using Sobol index in R language.

Could you please help me with the code. I am new to R and struggling with this.

Comment: See CRAN package `sensitivity`.

Comment: Sample code will be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. I left blank the part where you need to parametrize the different distribution

```
library(EnvStats) # where there is the qtri() function for the triangular distribution.

makeMCSample <- function(n, vals, p = 1) {
  # Packages to generate quasi-random sequences
  # and rearrange the data
  require(randtoolbox)
  require(plyr)
  
  # Generate a Sobol' sequence
  
  if (p == 2){
  sob <- sobol(n, length(vals), seed = 1234, scrambling = 1)
  }else{sob <- sobol(n, length(vals), scrambling = 1)}
  
  # Fill a matrix with the values
  # inverted from uniform values to
  # distributions of choice
  samp <- matrix(rep(0,n*(length(vals)+1)), nrow=n)
  samp[,1] <- 1:n
  for (i in 1:length(vals)) {
    # i=1
    l <- vals[[i]]
    dist <- l$dist
    params <- l$params
    fname <- paste("q",dist,sep="")
    samp[,i+1] <- do.call(fname,c(list(p=sob[,i]),params))
  }
  
  # Convert matrix to data frame and add labels
  samp <- as.data.frame(samp)
  names(samp) <- c("n",laply(vals, function(l) l$var))
  return(samp)
}
name = c("a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e")
vals <- list(list(var="a",dist="lnorm",params=list()), # Need to fill the input for the funtion qlnorm()
             list(var="b",dist="tri",params=list()), # Need to fill the input for the funtion qtri()
             list(var="c",dist="beta",params=list()), # Need to fill the input for the funtion qbeta()
             list(var="d",dist="weibull",params=list()), # Need to fill the input for the funtion qweibull()
             list(var="e",dist="gamma",params=list())) # Need to fill the input for the funtion qgamma()
k = 5
b = 10
M = 2^b

X1 <- makeMCSample(n,vals, p = 1)
X2 <- makeMCSample(n,vals, p = 2)


library(sensitivity)
x <- sobol2007(model = NULL, X1, X2, nboot = M)
y = x$X$a * x$X$b * x$X$c /(x$X$d * x$X$e)
tell(x,y)
ggplot(x)
print(x)
```

Sampling size = 7168 runs

Hope it help. I don't understand the use of nboot in it full complexity but see ref

ref : Qiong-Li Wu, Paul-Henry Cournède, Amélie Mathieu, 2012.
An efficient computational method for global sensitivity analysis and its application to tree growth modelling

Comment: This script is not yet validated. Use with caution